# Google Cloud SDK failed to install '.exe;.bat;.com' is not a recognized command

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, sdk, installation

I'm trying to install google cloud SDK on a windows 10 laptop. I tried removing the whitespace in the install folder, and added the path to my environmental variables. The full error is:

```
Output folder: C:\Users\user\Documents
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Users\user\Documents\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to install.
```

my environmental variables path :

C:\Users\user\Documents
C:\windows\system32

edit: I believe my problem is caused by the google SDK installation process trying to run a batch file. The batch file is not being recognized for some reason (although I verified it exists) so I'm thinking something is wrong with my path, or my network admin disabled batch files.

Comment: I disagree, I think my problem is related to a batch file not running when installing google SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to add the variables to your windows environmental variables configuration.

To do that, press WIN + X and then click on System.

On the left side, select the Advanced System Settings. Click on Environment Variables.

At the system variables panel, choose Path and then click the Edit button.

You can add the Environmental variables along with their path from there.

Comment: thanks, I know how to edit my path as I've already stated in the question. what do you propose I add to my path that I don't already have?