# Google Cloud SDK Failing To Get Installed

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, sdk, installation

I tried installing the Google Cloud SDK for Windows platform. But I'm facing some issues while installing it.
This is what I get as soon as the installation fails:

```
Output folder: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to install.
```

I have already set all these commands inside the PATHEXT command variable but I am still not able to install it. Please help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: apparently something isn't liking paths with spaces in them that aren't quoted.  Are you specifying any paths that contain spaces with no quotes ... see https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/administration/10886/jboss-won-t-start-problem-with-standalone-bat

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kolban. So I have a %JAVA_HOME% variable with the path as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201` without any quotes. And my PATH variable has a path `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. Also, I checked for any other paths with spaces and I couldn't find any path with spaces, but there is one particular path with spaces which points to the Python Shell Script. Does this path have anything to do with the SDK (since the SDK Files contain initialization scripts written in Python)? Should i quote this path as well?

Comment: here is another possible clue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201142/google-cloud-sdk-failed-to-install-exe-bat-com-is-not-a-recognized-command

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kolban... Appreciate your help mate :)